# C++ how to check if given input exists in the vector of pairs?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, vector, std-pair

There is a simple phone book with the content given in a vector. The program should ask the user to enter a name and present the number if exists and warn otherwise. And it should leave the phone book with Exit. I am getting an error for iterator part. How can I fix that?

I created an iterator for that purpose: `vector <pair < string , string >>::iterator it;` however I am getting the error: `invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char> >' and 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>')`

```
int main()
{
    //phone book
    vector <pair < string , string >>
    vec { make_pair ("Homer", "1111"),
    make_pair ("Marge", "2222"),
    make_pair ("Lisa", "3333"),
    make_pair ("Magy", "4444"),
    make_pair ("Bart", "5555")};

    std::string nameEntered;
    vector <pair < string , string >>::iterator it; //create iterator

    //unless Exit entered;
    while(nameEntered != "Exit"){

            //take input from user
            cout<<"Enter name (or Exit ): ";
            std::cin >> nameEntered; 

            it = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), nameEntered);
            //if given input exists, returns the corresponding phone number
            if(it != vec.end()){

            std::cout << "Phone number is: " << (*it).second << endl; //displays the phone number for given input name

            }

            else{

                std::cout << "No such phone number!"; //warns the user
            }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error: `invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char> >' and 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>')`. The expected output is the phone number of given input name.

Comment: Use a map.  It is created for situations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead

```
it = std::find_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
                   [&nameEntered]( const auto &p ) { return p.first == nameEntered; } );
```

Otherwise you are trying to compare an object of the type `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` with an object of the type `std::string` as the error message says.

Pay attention to that the condition of the loop is not good.

```
while(nameEntered != "Exit"){

        //take input from user
        cout<<"Enter name (or Exit ): ";
        std::cin >> nameEntered; 
        //...
```

because it will use the string `"Exit"` in the call of the algorithm.

Comment: using a map is easier

Comment: It says "error: 'auto' not allowed in lambda parameter"

Comment: @L.F. I agree. But this does not explain the error.:)

Comment: @excalibur26 Change it to const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &p.